# jQuery Validation on check box click disable TextBox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to get this JavaScript work for me.

Can any one help me with this.

When user clicks the Check box the next text box should disable,
if unchecked then enable.

selectors are working fine when I debug scrip in IE9 developer tool.

function is running fine as needed.

```
<input id="RefillNeeded10" name="RefillasNeeded" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input type="text" size="5" id="RefillTB10," name="Refills">
```

---

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name^="RefillasNeeded"]').click(function () {
var num = $(this).attr('id').replace("RefillNeeded", "");
if ($('input[type="checkbox"][id="RefillNeeded' + num + '"]').attr("checked")) {
  $('input[type="text"][id="RefillTB' + num + '"]').attr("disabled", true);
                   }
  else {
  $('input[type="text"][id="RefillTB' + num + '"]').attr("disabled", false);
   }
 });
```

but `$('input[type="text"][id="RefillTB' + num + '"]').attr("disabled", true);`
this is not creating the attribute disable.

I have this listed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/habo/KJVCa/1/) for convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector isn't matching any elements.  It looks like you have a typo in your HTML - there is a trailing `,` in the `id` of the text box.  Remove the comma from your id attribute, and it should work.  http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/KJVCa/13/

---

By the way, you don't need that big long selector to get the checkbox and test if it is checked.  You already have a reference to it as `this`.  And you can just check its `checked` property:

```
if (this.checked)
```

While we're at it, why not really simplify things.  You don't need to parse the id, just get the next element (assuming your textbox always follows your checkbox).  You don't need an `if`, just use the boolean directly.  Your code can be shrunk down to just this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox][name^=RefillasNeeded]").click(function () {
    $(this).next().attr("disabled", this.checked);
});
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/KJVCa/15/

Answer (score 0):

Also for the javascript I had to change

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][id="RefillNeeded' + num + '"]').attr("checked")
```

To

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][id="RefillNeeded' + num + '"]').is(":checked")
```

to get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
$('input[type="text"][id="RefillTB' + num + '"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

and

```
$('input[type="text"][id="RefillTB' + num + '"]').attr("disabled", "");
```

to

```
$('input[type="text"]["#RefillTB' + num + '"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

and

```
$('input[type="text"]["#RefillTB' + num + '"]').removeAttr("disabled");
```

respectively.

Comment: No, that will not work - that is not a valid selector.  I'm surprised it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: @gilly3 Actually, you were right. That shouldn't work and I feel silly for even proposing this. It does work in the example above, however, simply due to the fact that `$('input[type="text"]["#RefillTB' + num + '"]')` will get all the `<input>` elements and disable all on click. In other words - the second `[]` filter doesn't affect the result of the first one.